# Using if else on a dataframe across multiple columns

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop, dataframe

I have a large dataset of samples with descriptors of whether the sample is viable - it looks (kind of) like this, where 'desc' is the description column and 'blank' indicates the sample is not viable:

```
     desc        x        y        z
1   blank 4.529976 5.297952 5.581013
2   blank 5.906855 4.557389 4.901660
3  sample 4.322014 4.798248 4.995959
4  sample 3.997565 5.975604 7.160871
5   blank 4.898922 7.666193 5.551385
6   blank 5.667884 5.195825 5.232072
7   blank 5.524773 6.726074 4.767475
8  sample 4.382937 5.926217 5.203737
9  sample 4.976908 3.079191 4.614121
10  blank 4.572954 4.772373 6.077195
```

I want to use an if else statement to set the rows with unuseable data to NA. The final data set should look like this:

```
     desc        x        y        z
1   blank       NA       NA       NA
2   blank       NA       NA       NA
3  sample 4.322014 4.798248 4.995959
4  sample 3.997565 5.975604 7.160871
5   blank       NA       NA       NA
6   blank       NA       NA       NA
7   blank       NA       NA       NA
8  sample 4.382937 5.926217 5.203737
9  sample 4.976908 3.079191 4.614121
10  blank       NA       NA       NA
```

I have tried a for loop, but I'm having trouble getting the for-loop to change all the columns in one loop. My real dataset has 40 columns, so I'd rather not have to process it in separate loops! Here is the code to change one column at a time:

```
for(i in 1:length(desc)){
    if(dat$desc[i] =="blank"){
    dat$x[i] <- NA
    } 
    else {
    dat$x[i] <- dat$x[i]
    }
}
```

I made the sample data with this script:

```
desc <- c("blank", "blank", "sample", "sample", "blank", "blank", "blank",    "sample", "sample", "blank")
x <-  rnorm(10, mean=5, sd=1)
y <-  rnorm(10, mean=5, sd=1)
z <-  rnorm(10, mean=5, sd=1)

dat <- data.frame(desc,x,y,z)
```

Sorry if this is a basic question, I've spent all morning looking at forums and haven't been able to find a solution.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For your example dataset this will work;

Option 1, name the columns to change:

```
dat[which(dat$desc == "blank"), c("x", "y", "z")] <- NA
```

In your actual data with 40 columns, if you just want to set the last 39 columns to NA, then the following may be simpler than naming each of the columns to change;

Option 2, select columns using a range:

```
dat[which(dat$desc == "blank"), 2:40] <- NA
```

Option 3, exclude the 1st column:

```
dat[which(dat$desc == "blank"), -1] <- NA
```

Option 4, exclude a named column:

```
dat[which(dat$desc == "blank"), !names(dat) %in% "desc"] <- NA
```

As you can see, there are many ways to do this kind of operation (this is far from a complete list), and understanding how each of these options works will help you to get a better understanding of the language.

Comment: Thankyou so much, I think option 2 will be the one to go with :) 

And thanks for the additional examples! I hadn't come across which() before.

Answer (score 8):

Here's another dplyr solution with a small custom function and `mutate_each()`.

```
library(dplyr)

f <- function(x) if_else(dat$desc == "blank", NA_real_, x)
dat %>% 
  mutate_each(funs(f), -desc)
#>      desc        x        y        z
#> 1   blank       NA       NA       NA
#> 2   blank       NA       NA       NA
#> 3  sample 3.624941 6.430955 5.486632
#> 4  sample 3.236359 4.935453 4.319202
#> 5   blank       NA       NA       NA
#> 6   blank       NA       NA       NA
#> 7   blank       NA       NA       NA
#> 8  sample 5.058725 6.751650 4.750529
#> 9  sample 5.837206 4.323562 4.914780
#> 10  blank       NA       NA       NA
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I went with dww's one-line solution above, but this looks good too :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use dplyr and a custom function to mutate values on certain conditions.

`

```
library(dplyr)
mutate_cond <- function(.data, condition, ..., envir = parent.frame()) {
        condition <- eval(substitute(condition), .data, envir)
        .data[condition, ] <- .data[condition, ] %>% mutate(...)
        .data
}
data <- data %>% 
mutate_cond( desc == "blank", x = NA, y = NA, z = NA)
```

`

Answer (score 3):

Using your first initial approach with loops I figured out this:

```
    for(i in 1:nrow(dat)){
  if(dat[i, 1] =="blank"){
    dat[i, 2:4] <- NA
  } 
  else {
    dat[i,length(dat)] <- dat[i, length(dat)]
  }
}
```

I tested it with your data and worked. Hope this is useful for everyone dealing with loops in rows and columns with conditions.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for commenting - I'm sure someone will find this useful one day :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using `set` from `data.table`.  It should be faster as the overhead of `[.data.table` is avoided.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), loop through the column names of 'df1' (excluding the 'desc' column'), assign the elements to "NA" where the logical condition is 'i' is met.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
for(j in names(df1)[-1]){
   set(df1, i= which(df1[["desc"]]=="blank"), j= j, value= NA)
}
df1
#      desc        x        y        z
# 1:  blank       NA       NA       NA
# 2:  blank       NA       NA       NA
# 3: sample 4.322014 4.798248 4.995959
# 4: sample 3.997565 5.975604 7.160871
# 5:  blank       NA       NA       NA
# 6:  blank       NA       NA       NA
# 7:  blank       NA       NA       NA
# 8: sample 4.382937 5.926217 5.203737
# 9: sample 4.976908 3.079191 4.614121
#10:  blank       NA       NA       NA
```

Or another option (based on @dww's comment)

```
setDT(df1, key = "desc")["blank", names(df1)[-1] := NA][]
```

Comment: or, if using data tables, just df1[desc=="blank", c(2:NCOL(df1)):=NA, with=F] would do it.

Comment: @dww It could be done, but i think `set` would be fast

Comment: microbenchmarking these, it seems that the version in my comment is an order of magnitude faster. As you say, set should be fast. Could it be the overhead of which(df1[[ that slows your one?

Comment: @dww microbenchmarking with a large dataset or the example showed by the OP?

Comment: I used 100,000 rows, but just the 4 columns of OP.

Comment: @dww Okay, then your method should be  fast

Answer (score 2):

Here is another dplyr solution, using the new function across:

```
library(dplyr)

f <- function(x)ifelse(desc=="blank", NA, x)
dat %>% 
  mutate(across(.cols = c(x,y,z), .fns=f))
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Though honestly, if the data is unusable, why not delete the rows altogether?

```
library(dplyr)

blanks = 
  dat %>%
  filter(desc == "blank") %>%
  select(desc)

dat %>%
  filter(desc == "sample") %>%
  bind_rows(blanks)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to answer :) I definitely need to get more familiar with dplyr, it seems to be really useful. And as for deleting it, it's a timeseries (at 0.5 second intervals) and I think it would make my life harder in the long run if I deleted the bad rows!