# Recode missing values in multiple columns: mutate with across and ifelse

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I am working with an SPSS file that has been exported as tab delimited. In SPSS, you can set values to represent different types of missing and the dataset has 98 and 99 to indicate missing.

I want to convert them to NA but only in certain columns (V2 and V3 in the example data, leaving V1 and V4 unchanged).

```
library(dplyr)
testdf <- data.frame(V1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                     V2 = c(1, 98, 99, 2),
                     V3 = c(1, 99, 2, 3),
                     V4 = c(98, 99, 1, 2))
outdf <- testdf %>% 
  mutate(across(V2:V3), . = ifelse(. %in% c(98,99), NA, .))
```

I haven't used `across` before and cannot work out how to have the `mutate` return the `ifelse` into the same columns. I suspect I am overthinking this, but can't find any similar examples that have both `across` and `ifelse`. I need a tidyverse answer, prefer dplyr or tidyr.

Comment: Almost a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/37313347/680068 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/67520955/680068

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the syntax to be slightly different to make it work. Check `?across` for more info.

1. You need to use a `~` to make a valid function (or use `\(.)`, or use `function(.)`),
2. You need to include the formula in the `across` function

```r
library(dplyr)
testdf %>% 
  mutate(across(V2:V3, ~ ifelse(. %in% c(98,99), NA, .)))

#   V1 V2 V3 V4
# 1  1  1  1 98
# 2  2 NA NA 99
# 3  3 NA  2  1
# 4  4  2  3  2
```

---

Note that an alternative is `replace`:

```r
testdf %>% 
  mutate(across(V2:V3, ~ replace(., . %in% c(98,99), NA)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Base `R` option using `lapply` with an `ifelse` like this:

```r
cols <- c("V2","V3")
testdf[,cols] <- lapply(testdf[,cols],function(x) ifelse(x %in% c(98,99),NA,x))
testdf
#>   V1 V2 V3 V4
#> 1  1  1  1 98
#> 2  2 NA NA 99
#> 3  3 NA  2  1
#> 4  4  2  3  2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Base **R**:

```
cols <- c("V2", "V3")
testdf[, cols ][ testdf[, cols ] > 97 ] <- NA
```